# Lazy evaluation in async environment throwing exceptions using HashSet

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-core

I have a method below that maps id's to a collection of MyRecord's into a Dictionary.

The Dictionary value is evaluated lazily because of the Select.

The result of this method call is used elsewhere as a thread safe variable in an async environment.

Callers of that class retrieve the list of records for a given id and materialize it.

`_cache = await BuildCache();`

`var list = _cache[id].ToList();`

***What happens if two threads Materialize a value at the same time?***

**T1**: `_cache[123].ToList();`

**T2**: `_cache[123].ToList();`

```
        private async Task<IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<MyRecord>> BuildCache()
        {
            var records = await _repo.GetAll();
            return BuildMap(records);
        }

        private IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<MyRecord>> BuildMap(IEnumerable<MyRecord> records)
        {
            var internStrings = new HashSet<string>();

            var map = records?
                .GroupBy(x => x.PersonId)
                .ToDictionary((k) => k.Key, (v) => v.Select(t =>
                {
                    if (internStrings.TryGetValue(t.Title, out string interned))
                        t.Title= interned;
                    else
                        internStrings.Add(t.Title);
                    return t;
                }));

            return map;

        }
```

The reason I ask is because the hashSet is throwing an error when resizing from `internStrings.Add(t.Title)`,

***Is the lazy evaluation tripping over itself when multiple threads are materializing?***

***This is the Exception:**

```
System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough. Check the destination index, length, and the array's lower bounds.
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.SetCapacity(Int32 newSize)
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.IncreaseCapacity()
   at System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T value)
```

Note: the underlying IEnumerable comes from a dapper query not EF and I'm not asking about LINQ to SQL

`connection.QueryAsync<MyRecord>(SqlQueries.MyQuery, commandTimeout: _commandTimeout))`

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? Your `BuildMap` method isn't async,

Comment: What is the line where exception has been thrown?

Comment: @this is pseudo code but I moved the await to the repo call

Comment: @fabio exception is from `internStrings.Add(t.Title);`

Comment: It would be helpful if you gave the exception that is getting thrown.

Comment: @Smolakian this is the exception: `System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough. Check the destination index, length, and the array's lower bounds.
`

Comment: Use `ConcurrentDictionary<K, V>` instead of hash. hash is not thread safe

Comment: @Fabio Isn't a variable local to a method thread safe?

Comment: You are using that in lambda capture, it seems a local variable but got promoted to a class member by compiler.

Comment: Can you point me to documentation about "lambda capture promoting variables"?

Comment: I assume that method `await _repo.GetAll();` will "materialize" retrieved data, so you already dealing with in-memory data. If no - that would be big surprise ...

Comment: I would suggest to create a repository method `GetAllByPersonId(int personId)` and call from anywhere without cache.

Comment: When you have a reference to a `Dictionary<K,V>` object, it has already been materialized. If you want it to be created lazily, you must use a `Lazy<Dictionary<K,V>>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems very likely that while one thread is resizing another thread comes along and changes the array size, resulting in the exception  you are seeing.

I would advice you get rid of the `HashSet<string>` and use `string.Intern()` directly if you are concerned about string instances.

```
    private async Task<IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<MyRecord>> BuildCache()
    {
        var records = await _repo.GetAll();
        return BuildMap(records);
    }

    private IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<MyRecord>> BuildMap(IEnumerable<MyRecord> records)
    {
        var map = records?
            .GroupBy(x => x.PersonId)
            .ToDictionary((k) => k.Key, (v) => v.Select(t => { t.Title = string.Intern(t.Title); return t; }));

        return map;

    }
```

Comment: I was avoiding using build in`string.Intern` because I only want to keep it in memory for the lifetime of the method call (i.e. whenever cache is rebuilt) as opposed to the lifetime of the application or longer..from docs: `the memory allocated for interned String objects is not likely to be released until the common language runtime (CLR) terminates`

Comment: Good luck with that! A `ConcurrentDictionary<T,K>` is your best bet and has a much higher memory foot print and because it will be captured by a lambda expression in async context a lifetime unfathomable by mere mortals.

Comment: What about Materializing it after the Select? `(v) => v.Select(t => { t.Title = string.Intern(t.Title); return t; }).ToList()`

Comment: This buys you nothing, the `string.Intern()` call is still there.

Comment: I meant this:                                                                                                           ```.ToDictionary((k) => k.Key, (v) => v.Select(t =>
               {
                   if (internStrings.TryGetValue(t.Title, out string interned))
                       t.Title = interned;
                   else
                       internStrings.Add(t.Title);
                   return t;
               }).ToList()                                                                                                 ```

Comment: Yes! That should break the link between this LINQ query and the async context.

Comment: That leads me to my next question..the model is an IEnumerable so I would have to do this: `.ToList().AsEnumerable()` - does that "dematerialize" the collection? i.e. next time it's accessed it will me materialized again?